# perl one liner + how to match IP address that located in the first/sec field of file

Tags: linux, shell-script, solaris, perl, ksh

the following perl one liner syntax verify if IP address in "$IP" match the IP ADDRESS in file

```
     perl -ne 'BEGIN{$IP=shift} print if /(^|\s)\Q$IP\E(\s|$)/;' $IP file
```

file have two fields

as the following example

```
more file


192.9.200.1  172.19.2.100
10.23.1.10   34.12.0.1
45.2.11.1    192.9.200.1
.
.
.
```

is it possible to define the perl syntax to match the IP that exists in the first field or the second field ? 
- if yes what I need to change in my syntax for that?

for example ( in case we want to match only the first field )

```
     perl -ne 'BEGIN{$IP=shift} print if /(^|\s)\Q$IP\E(\s|$)/;' 192.9.200.1 file
```

then it should to match the IP - 192.9.200.1 that exists in the first field of the line:

```
   "192.9.200.1  172.19.2.100"
```

Comment: +1 for your use of `\Q` and complex boundary markers.

Answer (score 2):

I would use perl's "auto-splitting" option [`-a`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) and stay away from regexes

```
perl -lane 'BEGIN{$IP=shift} print if $F[0] eq $IP or $F[1] eq $IP' $IP file
perl -lane 'BEGIN{$IP=shift} print if grep {$_ eq $IP} @F[0,1]' $IP file
```

`-l` gives you automatic `chomp`ing and automatic newlines for print statement.

awk is simpler:

```
awk -v ip=$IP '$1==ip || $2==ip' file
```

---

A second reading of the question indicates you might want to match only the first column or only the 2nd column. To pass the column number as a parameter:

```
perl -lane '
    BEGIN {($IP,$col) = splice @ARGV,0,2}
    print if $F[$col-1] eq $IP
' $IP 2 file
```

```
awk -v ip=$IP -v col=2 '$col == ip' file
```

These return, given your sample data:

```
45.2.11.1    192.9.200.1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the "there's more than one way to do it file". :-)

Another way to find the IP address either in column one or column two is to use grep.

For column 1:

```
grep ^192.9.200.1 file
```

This outputs all lines with your IP in the first column.

For column 2:

```
grep 192.9.200.1$ file
```

This outputs all lines with your IP in the last column.

I like the solution Glenn came up with using awk to see if IP is in both column 1 & 2, it's nice and readable.